# Seek advise on creating sqlite query to process buy sell transactions according to FIFO method and produce a combine summary

Tags: sqlite, subquery, fifo

I am attempting to create a sqlite query to process stocks buy sell transaction based on FIFO method to track summary of counters performance.

There are 2 queries written so far:

1. Matching 1 buy and 1 sell transaction to track down the transaction performance, please refer "fifo_command _match_obos_query.txt" below for detail.

```
WITH Purchase AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS rn FROM trans_fifo WHERE txtype = 'buy'
),

Dispose AS ( 
    SELECT item, qty, amount ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS s FROM trans_fifo WHERE txtype = 'sell'
)
SELECT
      p.item Counter, round(d.amount - p.amount,2) PL
FROM
    Purchase p
        LEFT JOIN
    Dispose d
        ON
          p.item = d.item and p.qty = d.qty and p.rn = d.s
WHERE PL NO NULL
;
```

Produce this output:

```
Counter  PL
-------  ------
AEMULUS  47.74
ARMADA   103.84
BAUTO    162.84
CIMB     150.48
D&O      85.49
EFORCE   90.46
HEVEA    200.55
IRIS     55.42
JCY      36.0
JCY      -261.9
KPJ      191.9
MBMR     273.25
MBMR     173.12
MBSB     22.77
RSAWIT   173.3
SUCCESS  110.88
TNLOGIS  120.38
VELESTO  127.0
```

2. Matching multiple buy and 1 sell transaction to track down the transaction performance, please refer "fifo_command _match_mbos_query.txt" for detail.

```
WITH Purchase AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS rn FROM trans_fifo WHERE txtype = 'buy'
),

Dispose AS ( 
    SELECT item, qty, amount ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS s FROM trans_fifo WHERE txtype = 'sell'
)
SELECT
      p.item Counter, round(d.amount - sum(p.amount),2) PL
FROM
    Purchase p
        LEFT JOIN
    Dispose d
        ON
          p.item = d.item and p.qty <> d.qty
GROUP BY p.item
;
```

Produce this output

```
Counter  PL
-------  ------
AEMULUS  [NULL]
ARMADA   [NULL]
ARREIT   [NULL]
BAUTO    [NULL]
CIMB     [NULL]
D&O      [NULL]
EFORCE   [NULL]
GENM     [NULL]
HEVEA    [NULL]
IGBREIT  [NULL]
IRIS     [NULL]
JCY      [NULL]
KPJ      [NULL]
MBMR     [NULL]
MBSB     [NULL]
N2N      57.21
RSAWIT   [NULL]
SUCCESS  [NULL]
SUNREIT  [NULL]
TNLOGIS  [NULL]
TWREIT   [NULL]
VELESTO  [NULL]
VIS      331.69
YTLPOWR  88.19
```

My request is how could I make use of these queries (or please suggest what are the better way to address this scenario) to compose an efficient query to produce a output to include both scenarios in one summary like below ?

```
Counter  PL
-------  ------
AEMULUS  47.74
ARMADA   103.84
BAUTO    162.84
CIMB     150.48
D&O      85.49
EFORCE   90.46
HEVEA    200.55
IRIS     55.42
JCY      36.0
JCY      -261.9
KPJ      191.9
MBMR     273.25
MBMR     173.12
MBSB     22.77
RSAWIT   173.3
SUCCESS  110.88
TNLOGIS  120.38
VELESTO  127.0
N2N      57.21
VIS      331.69
YTLPOWR  88.19
```

Sample data trans_fifo table for testing below:

```
item     date        txtype  qty    price  amount
-------  ----------  ------  -----  -----  -------
AEMULUS  2020-09-17  buy     1000   0.67   678.62
AEMULUS  2020-10-23  sell    1000   0.735  726.36
ARMADA   2020-06-01  buy     2000   0.24   487.56
ARMADA   2020-09-02  sell    2000   0.3    591.4
ARREIT   2020-06-24  buy     2000   0.68   1370.95
CIMB     2021-01-21  buy     1000   3.98   3994.73
CIMB     2021-02-10  sell    1000   4.16   4145.21
D&O      2020-12-31  buy     1000   2.34   2352.24
D&O      2021-01-05  sell    1000   2.45   2437.73
EFORCE   2020-06-16  buy     2000   0.455  918.69
EFORCE   2020-07-28  sell    2000   0.51   1009.15
GENM     2020-02-26  buy     2000   2.93   5877.3
GENM     2020-12-07  buy     2000   2.56   5136.08
HEVEA    2020-09-11  buy     5000   0.435  2187.19
HEVEA    2020-09-29  sell    5000   0.48   2387.74
IGBREIT  2020-06-26  buy     1000   1.81   1822.08
IGBREIT  2021-01-08  buy     1000   1.68   1692.04
IGBREIT  2021-01-13  buy     1000   1.64   1652.03
IRIS     2020-07-03  buy     5000   0.2    1008.72
IRIS     2020-07-06  sell    5000   0.215  1064.14
JCY      2020-09-09  buy     2000   0.75   1511.99
JCY      2020-09-09  sell    2000   0.78   1547.99
JCY      2020-09-10  buy     2000   0.745  1500.99
JCY      2020-11-24  sell    2000   0.625  1239.09
KPJ      2020-10-22  buy     1800   0.88   1596.02
KPJ      2020-12-07  sell    1800   1.0    1787.92
MBMR     2020-10-30  buy     1000   2.63   2643.33
MBMR     2020-11-05  sell    1000   2.93   2916.58
MBMR     2020-11-10  buy     1000   2.9    2913.41
MBMR     2020-11-13  sell    1000   3.1    3086.53
MBSB     2021-01-13  buy     1000   0.625  633.61
MBSB     2021-02-16  sell    1000   0.665  656.38
N2N      2020-09-04  buy     2000   0.795  1602.02
N2N      2020-09-07  buy     1000   0.775  783.65
N2N      2020-09-10  buy     1000   0.695  703.63
N2N      2021-02-10  sell    4000   0.79   3146.51
RSAWIT   2020-09-24  buy     10000  0.26   2613.32
RSAWIT   2020-10-12  sell    10000  0.28   2786.62
SUCCESS  2020-07-27  buy     3000   0.56   1692.04
SUCCESS  2020-08-07  sell    3000   0.605  1802.92
SUCCESS  2021-01-22  buy     2000   0.79   1592.01
SUCCESS  2021-01-26  buy     2000   0.75   1511.99
SUCCESS  2021-02-18  buy     4000   0.74   2973.43
SUNREIT  2020-05-28  buy     1000   1.57   1582.01
SUNREIT  2020-10-06  buy     1000   1.5    1511.99
SUNREIT  2021-01-06  buy     1000   1.4    1410.96
TNLOGIS  2021-02-04  buy     5000   0.83   4164.79
TNLOGIS  2021-02-08  sell    5000   0.86   4285.17
TWREIT   2020-06-07  buy     2000   0.705  1420.96
VELESTO  2020-08-07  buy     10000  0.145  1460.98
VELESTO  2021-02-17  sell    10000  0.16   1587.98
VIS      2020-09-30  buy     5000   0.48   2412.26
VIS      2020-10-07  buy     1000   0.445  452.55
VIS      2020-12-07  sell    6000   0.535  3196.5
YTLPOWR  2020-02-07  buy     1000   0.725  733.64
YTLPOWR  2020-02-26  buy     2000   0.695  1400.96
YTLPOWR  2020-10-23  sell    3000   0.745  2222.79
BAUTO    2021-02-04  buy     5000   1.34   6718.55
BAUTO    2021-02-08  sell    5000   1.38   6881.39
```

trans_fifo schema below:

```
sqlite> .schema trans_fifo
CREATE VIEW trans_fifo
AS
SELECT
   --broker.name as broker,
   --investor.name as investor,
   stock.counter as item,
   trans.date as date,
   type.tname as txtype,
   trans.unit as qty,
   trans.price as price,
   trans.amount as amount
FROM
   trans
   INNER JOIN investor on investor.investor_id=trans.investor_id
   INNER JOIN broker on broker.broker_id=trans.broker_id
   INNER JOIN stock on stock.stock_id=trans.stock_id
   INNER JOIN type on type.ttype=trans.ttype
WHERE
   investor.name = 'SOON' AND broker.name = 'RAKUTEN'
   -- stock.counter = 'SLP' AND investor.investor_id=1
ORDER BY
   trans.broker_id ASC,
   trans.stock_id ASC
/* trans_fifo(item,date,txtype,qty,price,amount) */;
```

Thank you and appreciate your time to shade some light and insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out a few days, here is the solution on my own posting:

The solution utilise sqlite window frame functions to add caculation/manipulation variables to achieve the purpose.

```
WITH Purchase AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS rn, 
        COUNT(item) OVER (PARTITION BY item) AS crn,
           SUM(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER By item, date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS bqsum,
               SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER By item, date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS amsum 
    FROM trans_fifo WHERE txtype = 'buy'
),
Dispose AS ( 
    SELECT item, date, qty, amount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS s     
    FROM trans_fifo WHERE txtype = 'sell' --GROUP BY item
)
SELECT
      p.item,   
        (CASE 
            WHEN 
                 p.item=out.item AND p.qty = d.qty AND p.rn = d.s THEN round(d.amount - p.amount,2)
            WHEN                 
                 p.item=d.item AND p.bqsum = d.qty AND d.date >= p.date THEN round(d.amount - p.amsum,2)
         END) PL 
FROM
    Purchase p
        LEFT JOIN
    Dispose d
        ON
           p.item = d.item
WHERE
   PL IS NOT NULL
```

Here is the end result:

```
item     PL
-------  ------
AEMULUS  47.74
ARMADA   103.84
BAUTO    162.84
CIMB     150.48
D&O      85.49
EFORCE   90.46
HEVEA    200.55
IRIS     55.42
JCY      36.0
JCY      -261.9
KPJ      191.9
MBMR     273.25
MBMR     173.12
MBSB     22.77
N2N      57.21
RSAWIT   173.3
SUCCESS  110.88
SUCCESS  265.12
TNLOGIS  120.38
VELESTO  127.0
VIS      331.69
YTLPOWR  88.19
```